# Determing if Euler's Method Overestimates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eulers-method

How do you work out if Euler's method overestimates the actual solution, for the ODE:

$\frac{dy}{dx}=24\tan(\pi x)$

With steps of 0.25 from $1\le x\le 2$?

Comment: Based on what you know about the second derivative of $24 \tan (\pi x)$, are the local linear approximations above or below the function as you pick points in $[1,2]$?

Comment: @TheOkay The answer below seems spectacularly offtopic. How comes you accepted it? Note that this move suggests to users with an actual answer to your question that they should not post it.

Answer (score 0):

$dy = 24\tan({\pi x})dx \Leftrightarrow y(x) = \int 24\tan({\pi x})dx \Leftrightarrow \frac{24}{\pi}\int \tan(u)du = \frac{24}{\pi}\int \frac{sin(u)}{cos(u)} $

Let $s = \cos(u)$ then $ds = -\sin(u)du$ so you get :

$ -\frac{24}{\pi}\int \frac{1}{s}ds = -\frac{24}{\pi}\ln(s) + c $

Substitute $s$ back in and you get :

$ -\frac{24}{\pi}\ln(s) + c = -\frac{24}{\pi}\ln(cos(πx)) + c$

Now you can evaluate anything you want.

Comment: How do I go from that, to determining if Euler's method overestimates or not?

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your text. Try adding some commas (,) so that the sentences are read as they should. Without the commas I thought you had an issue applying Euler's Method and wanted the analytical general solution. Sorry :)

Comment: @TheOkayMan You now have the _actual_ solution for $y$. So you can find the exact values of $y(1), y(1.25)$ etc. You can then apply Eulers method to the same problem to find values of $y_{e}(1), y_{e}(1.25)$ etc and compare against the actual solutions.

Comment: He can still use the actual solution to find the exact values and apply Euler's method to find the values and see if it overestimates or not though.  (Despite the fact that I misread, this is still the answer that could lead him to his solution).

Comment: "Despite the fact that I misread, this is still the answer that could lead him to his solution" Actually no, an answer to the OP's question would use the convexity properties of $\tan$, not an analytic formula for the exact solution of the differential equation.